# SSISDB file size is not reduced even after deleting half of the history, why?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2014

We are using SQLServer 2014 and many SSIS packages are executed as part of daily/weekly jobs for about an year.
Today I reduced the retention period from 100 days to 50 days and ran the SSIS Server Maintenance job (runs daily).

But the mdf (44GB) and ldf (6GB) file sizes are not reduced.
Surprisngly, if you see the attachment, ldf is not modified since 28-Aug-2017.

SSISDB Backup is taken as part of Maintenance Plan everyday.

Iam sure, we don't have 50GB data in SSISDB, definitely less than that.

Why the SSISDB.mdf and SSISDB.ldf file sizes are not reduced even after deleting half of the history ?
How to release unused space in SSISDB (log or mdf or both) ?

Can any one help ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

SSISDB is just another Database.
In order for Database files to be reduced in size then it is also necessary to use DBCC SHRINKDATABASE.